# Infinite gas cost when trying to use transfer()

Tags: solidity, remix, address.transfer, embark

I tested the contract using Remix Javascript VM, Injected Web3(Ropsten) and in-built Ganache client from Embark Framework(4.0). Always getting infinite gas usage. Can someone please help me? This is my contract code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint prize = 100;
    function() external payable {}

   function prizeDistribution() public payable {
        msg.sender.transfer(prize);        
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working fine on mine, are you sending some ethers using fallback function before executing `prizeDistribution` ? Because if not, then your contract doesn't have enough Wei to transfer. Also the difference of  *prize* and *price* is bugging me.

Comment: @sp4c3 Its working in Remix  after calling fallback before `prizeDistribution`. But its still throwing errors in Truffle as well as Embark. Truffle:`truffle(ganache)>instance.prizeDistribution.call()
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

Comment: Here `instance.prizeDistribution.call()` should cause an error. You are trying to transfer `100 Wei` from **contract balance** to **another account**. But your contract doesn't have `100 Wei` as balance.